# gtk2 auto translation is choosing the wrong language

Tags: internationalization, gtk, gtk2

Not sure if yall can help this time, as I'm just using this particular program not coding with it...

I downloaded Deluge, a free torrent app, and it requires `GTK2 Runtime` which I've also installed. Unfortunately, on my English WinXP with East Asian Language support Deluge sets itself to Chinese menus and has no option to alter the language. A bit of poking around on the internet suggests this is due to GTK2 selecting the wrong default language.

Does anyone know how I can override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You caould try to change LC_MESSAGES or LANG environment variables to "C" (default locale, in 99% English) or your language code ("en" or "en_US" etc).